# Как можно полностью закрыть доступ к VDS

Tags: vds

Имеется тестовый сервер для работы. Подскажите, можно ли полностью закрыть к нему доступ извне , чтобы любые обращения к нему к любому порту отдавали отказ, но при этом, я мог на нем работать ?

Comment: Если любой порт будет давать отказ, то вы не сможете подключиться к нему для работы. Если личный кабиент хостера предоставляет VNC-доступ, то можно через него, а если нет, то нет

Comment: Ещё как вариант можно прокинуть какой-нибудь туннель, который будет сам подключаться из VDS к какому-нибудь другому компьютеру, а уже этот другой компьютер сможет подключиться к VDS через туннель. Но загвоздка в том, что на этом другом компьютере всё равно придётся держать какой-то открытый порт для подключения туннеля